# How to manage C++ dependencies

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2013

I am fairly new to the C++ dependency management through libraries and dlls.
I fully understand the difference between static and dynamic linking(I guess) which is why I am asking this, as common answers usually relate to issues with not understanding the difference.
I'm using visual studio and my current project is set up like this:

Bridge project: this is a dll project that exports a few classes. This serves as a shared library for bridge between networking code and application code.
Naturally, it has its own dependencies (ZMQ network library, MsgPack serialization, ...) which are statically linked (using .lib files). My .dll is generated normally and it's exported .lib file too. (Before I switched to dll project I kept compiling it as .exe to test the code as I coded...)

App project: This project is an application project and would like to use the bridge to gain full access to networking functionality via bridge. So I add the .lib dependency to it and I know I will have to supply the .dll to the .exe

However my problem is, that the application will not compile, because it is missing header files from ZMQ(which are a bridge .dll dependencies, and not relevant to the app at all, since only bridge internal BL uses them).
Is there any way I can "bake"/include all my required dependencies to the bridge dll (ZMQ, MsgPack, Log4cpp ....) and provided -just- the bridge.dll to the app (ofc, with bridge.lib as a library input)?
Am I misunderstanding something obvious here and am going at this completely the wrong way?

Thanks for help, greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Why would you need a bridge-dll at all, instead of just your application linking to everything needed directly?

Comment: If you are missing *headers*, most probably you have exported something defined in dependencies of the bridge, not bridge itself. Then naturally you  will need to include headers.

Comment: Read up on compiler firewall, opaque pointer, pimpl idiom for typical way to get rid of need to include headers of indirect dependencies.

Comment: Don't include "private" header files in the bridge libraries public header files.

Comment: Thanks Tiib and Pileborg, you were spot on about my problem. Unfortunately the library headers i include in my bridge do not have any classes i could forward declare but rather alot of constants and functions. Does the general pimpl idiom still apply for functions and constants or is there any better practise forward declaring high amount of functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue so I am gonna write up an answer to my problem.
Many thanks to all that helped, especially @Öö Tiib, @Joachim Pileborg.

The problem was that I included "private" libraries in my public bridge library. (I included "zmq.h" in bridge.h).

Since my header file does not contain anything from that library I have moved the "zmq.h" include to the bridge.cpp file.